# Unity3D, how i repeat the background image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to repeat the background image on the GUILayout.
After i search from the website, not able find out how to repeat the image.

is that can tell me why? or how i can make the windows background image able to auto fill?

below is my code.

```
Texture2D LzIMGBackground;
    LzIMGBackground = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Textures/UI/Resources/metal-background-texture.jpg",typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
    GUILayout.BeginVertical (LzIMGBackground, "box");
    GUILayout.BeginVertical ("box");
    if(GUILayout.Button("Single Player",GUILayout.Width(200))){
        Application.LoadLevel("testGUITransitions");
    }
    GUILayout.EndVertical ();

    GUILayout.BeginVertical ("box");
    if(GUILayout.Button("Quit",GUILayout.Width(200))){
        Application.Quit();
    }
    GUILayout.EndVertical ();
    GUILayout.EndVertical ();
```

and i had attach the file for example. thanks a lot.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: you can try pass a http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.html Guistyle object with a fixed width.

Comment: @AVolpe , thanks for reply. is that give me some example? i not really understand how to make it work.

Comment: @AVolpe , i had try it. but it just scale the image. is that got possible repeat the image without scale? thanks!

Comment: check this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14802/guiskin-tiling-instead-of-stretching-textures.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14802/guiskin-tiling-instead-of-stretching-textures.html) you need to use the 'GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords' function

```
var panelWidth = ...; 
var panelHeight = ...;
yourTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;

GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(panelPos, yourTexture, 
    new Rect(0, 0, screenBounds.width / yourTexture.width, panelHeight / yourTexture.height));
```

Comment: hope you can answer me another question. thanks alot! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268667/unity-how-to-set-the-sprite-in-front-the-background-image